# how to implement twitter in iphone app

Tags: ios

Is there any tutorial out there showing how to use OAuth on IPhone?I download it from Gitgub. I want to send a mesage from my app to twitter.How to implement this...Anybody help me to immlement this?Advance thanks

Comment: try this [tutorial](http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=1303) also [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/09/integrating-twitter-into-your-applications/) and [this](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa/)

Answer (score 1):

Another option: [DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController)

It uses OAuth for iOS4 and the built-in Twitter features in iOS5.

Answer (score 1):

sai, you might want to look at the Socialize SDK (http://www.getsocialize.com) which will help manage the entire Social Integration process (FB/Twitter) for you without needing to know OAuth.  Oauth is kind of a pain.